# Users are inactive/disabled with red "X" mark after solution deployment to Azure SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-managed-identity

We have solution for database project made in Visual Studio 2019 which contains of 3 projects. Main project contains scripts with user information in `Security` folder. We have users which have "EXTERNAL PROVIDER" method to authenticate in Azure Portal. Users are created in standard way/configuration from Visual Studio perspective or project is synchronized with existing Azure database:

[image]

The case is: after solution deployment to destination database in Azure (Azure SQL Server database) when we open Security folder we can see that all users have been created but they are not enabled/valid. Next to user icon we can see small red "X" like this:

[image].

We have also ADF application which connects to above Azure database using that user with "X". Unfortunately ADF is not able to establish connection giving error. What we have done to solve this issue was to drop that user and recreate it again with external provider method and assign to correct roles. After that ADF application was able to establish connection and query database. There are no longer red "X" icons next to users.

Could someone explain why we are getting that "X" user as invalid/inactive? Is something missing in configuration from Visual Studio perspective? The workaround for this is to drop and recreate user but we'd like to have this done via Visual Studio in one solution deployment.

Comment: Not sure but the first step is to generate the drift script and inspect it, particularly any CREATE USER steps

Comment: I checked the script for deployment and there was line: " REVOKE CONNECT TO <user>". I granted connect to this user in the same script it is created and works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for returning with a solution so that other people can make use of it. You should be able to post as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked script that was created for deployment and there was a part where this user was revoked connection to the database. I granted CONNECT to this user and that "red" mark disappeared. User can now connect to the database.